# When was the first use of "For sure"?

Tags: phrase-origin

When (approximately) was the first recorded use of "for sure" to mean "certainly"?

For example,

> I wanted it more than he did, for sure.

Comment: Please share what your research has shown so far.

Comment: In the past decade or so, it's become 'sportsman speech' especially with non-English natives being interviewed in English. "For sure, we played better in the first half…" [I used to count how many times Sebastian Vettel said it in any given race weekend.]

Answer (score 3):

According to [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/sure) the expression dates back to the late 16c.

***Sure:***

> As an affirmative meaning "yes, certainly" it dates from 1803, from Middle English meanings "firmly established; having no doubt," and phrases such as to be sure (1650s), sure enough (1540s), and ***for sure (1580s).***